# Mocking a non-settable child property with Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, mocking, rhino-mocks

I currently have interfaces much like the following:

```
interface IService
{
   void Start();
   IHandler ServiceHandler { get; }
}

interface IHandler
{
   event EventHandler OnMessageReceived;
}
```

Using Rhino Mocks, it's easy enough to mock IService, but it doesn't assign any `IHandler` instance to the `ServiceHandler` property.  Therefore when my method under test adds an event handler to `_mockedService.ServiceHandler.OnMessageReceived`, I get an 'Object reference not set' error.

How can I ensure that ServiceHandler is assigned a value in the mocked `IService` instance?

This is likely Rhino Mocks 101, but I'm just getting up to speed on it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
IService service = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IService>();
IHandler stubHandler = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IHandler>();
service.Stub(s => s.ServiceHandler).Return(stubHandler);

//assertions
```

Or you can use GenerateMock instead if you need to record expectations on your fakes.

EDIT: for older versions of RhinoMocks you can do this:

```
MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
IService service = mocks.CreateStub<IService>();
IHandler handler = mocks.CreateStub<IHandler>();

using (mocks.Record())
{
    SetupResult.For(service.ServiceHandler).Return(handler);
    //setup expectations using Expect.Call
}

using (mocks.Playback())
{
    //assertions
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing RM 3.3 (which I'm stuck using unfortunately) doesn't support the extension method syntax you've got there - any idea on the 3.3 syntax to achieve the same thing?